# Cant find a variable in a list

Tags: python, list, class

I wrote this code as a part of a course I am taking right now, and even though I asked some friends to debug it we didn't manage to find the problem in the code. It throws an error that the variable I am looking for cannot be found in the list, even though I can find it when I debug and the functions I use are supposed to find it. Can anyone help me fix it?

```
class Grade:
    def __init__(self, grade_val, grade_weight):
        if grade_weight > 4 or grade_weight < 1 or grade_val > 100 or grade_val < 0:
            print("Grade weight should be a number between 1 and 4 and Grade value should be between 0 and 100")
        else:
            self.grade_value = grade_val
            self.grade_weight = grade_weight

    def get_val(self):
        return self.grade_value

    def get_weight(self):
        return self.grade_weight


class Subject:
    def __init__(self, subject_name):
        self.name = subject_name
        self.grades = []

    def add_grade(self, grade):
        if not isinstance(grade, Grade):
            return "Wrong input"
        self.grades.append(grade)

    def avg(self):
        counter = 0
        grade_sum = 0
        for grade in self.grades:
            grade_sum += grade.get_val() * grade.get_weight()
            counter += grade.get_weight()
        return grade_sum / counter

    def __str__(self):
        grades_str = ""
        for grade in self.grades:
            grades_str += f"Val: {grade.get_val()} Weight: {grade.get_weight()}.   "
        return grades_str

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.grades)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Subject):
            return "Wrong input"
        if self.avg() > other.avg():
            return "Self avg is bigger"
        if self.avg() < other.avg():
            return "Other avg is bigger"
        return "Avgs are equal"

    def __gt__(self, other):
        self.__lt__(other)


class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, s_id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = s_id
        self.subjects = []

    def add_sub(self, subject):
        if not isinstance(subject, Subject):
            return "Wrong input"
        self.subjects.append(subject)

    def add_grade(self, subject, grade):
        if not isinstance(grade, Grade):
            return "Wrong input"
        for subj in self.subjects:
            if subj.name == subject:
                subj.add_grade(grade)
        # self.subjects[self.subjects.index(subject)].add_grade(grade)

    def get_subs(self):
        return self.subjects

    def sub_avg(self, subject):
        return self.subjects[self.subjects.index(subject)].avg()

    def student_avg(self):
        summ = 0
        for subject in self.subjects:
            summ += subject.avg()
        return summ / self.subjects.len()


std = Student("Ofek", 42069)
std.add_sub(Subject("Math"))
# subs = std.get_subs()
# for sub in subs:
#     print(sub.name)
#     print(std.subjects[0].name)
std.add_grade("Math", Grade(98, 4))
std.add_grade("Math", Grade(92, 2))
std.add_sub(Subject("English"))
std.add_grade("English", Grade(85, 3))
print(std.sub_avg("Math"))
print(std.student_avg())


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bar_m\Desktop\DevOps\Python\Code\grade_exe.py", line 99, in <module>
    print(std.sub_avg("Math"))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bar_m\Desktop\DevOps\Python\Code\grade_exe.py", line 80, in sub_avg
    return self.subjects[self.subjects.index(subject)].avg()
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: 'Math' is not in list
```

Thx for the support in advance <3

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: `__lt__` should return a boolean, not a string.

Comment: If the arguments to `Grade.__init__` cannot be used to initialize the two attributes, you should raise an exception. `__init__` should not return without correctly initializing the object.

Comment: we were told to write the __lt__ function this way, i dont really know why but just doing as told...

Comment: You were told wrong. The whole point of that method is so you can write `if subj1 < subj2:`. Your method will return a truthy value all the time.

Comment: Review the instructions.  I don’t think you’re actually supposed to implement comparators that way — maybe the instructions showed example code that CALLS the comparators to print those messages?  Read carefully and make sure you’re correctly understanding what the assignment wants you to do.  (I have guesses, but since I can’t see the assignment I’m going to refrain from answering based on a guess.)

Comment: And `__gt__()` needs to reverse the arguments. `return other.__lt__(self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sub_avg()`, `subject` is a string that names a subject, but `self.subjects` is a list of `Subject` instances, not strings. You need to loop through the list looking for the one with that name.

```
def sub_avg(self, subject):
    for sub in self.subjects:
        if sub.name == subject:
            return sub.avg()
    raise KeyError(f"Subject {subject} not found in {self}")
```